# Writing a number in a list, IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, ip

I would like to write a number in a list but this number comes from a variable. Indeed, I am reading packets and I am getting back the IP addresses. My list is first filled with 0 and when I got an IP address, I will put the end of the IP address at the right case at 1. And I want to count the number of 1 in the list.
For example (I don't know the IP adresses) :

```
Mydico=[]
for i in range(len(Mydico)):
    Mydico[i]=0
IP_address = '192.168.1.25'
nber=IP_address.split('.')[-1]# I got 25 in the variable nbre
Mydico[int(nber)]=1
print Mydico.count(1)
```

I got the following error :
Mydico [int(nber)]=1
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Edit : I did many changes because I mistook dictionaries and lists

Comment: You need to convert `nbre` to an integer.

Comment: As [Jkdc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4367228/jkdc) mentioned -> check [int()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
Mydico=[]
for i in range(len(Mydico)):
    Mydico[i]=0
```

len(mydico) will be zero. So your Mydico remains [].

and

```
IP_address = '192.168.1.25'
nber=IP_address.split('.')[-1]# I got 25 in the variable nbre
Mydico[int(nber)]=1
```

int(nber) is 25. you can not change mydico[25] because you don't have list that long.

Comment: what is the solution to that problem ?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want to do. but you can use dict in place of list. or you can initialise your list with range(255).

Answer (score 1):

IP_adress is a string here as you can use split on it. However if you want to index a list you have to give a number. So you'll need to cast it to integer

```
List[int(nbre)]=1
```

Usually using the name `List` (even if it's better than `list` which is a builtin) as a variable is not really a good practice.

**Edit:**
As OP changed his post to make appear MyList i will add some information.

First `Mylist = {}` create a dictionnary not a list. If you want to use a dictionnary you could use string as a key, and don't really need to convert to int. If you don't know what is a dictionnary I let you read [section 5.5](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

If you need to initialize an empty list you must do `Mylist = []`. If you want to add item to the list you must do `Mylist.append(foo)`. However if you do that you will add one number at a time.

Comment: I think there is a lack of understanding in you code. I just post an edit wich adress the modification you made to it

Comment: I did many changes concerning my problem, I am using list now but I would like to write 0 in all the cases of my list thanks to for loop, is is possible ?